# What is the best way to bind only certain properties to a datagridview WITHOUT using the browsable attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I have an class that I cannot modify. It has about 30 public properties on it. I need bind only 2 properties from this class to a datagridview to represent the whole object. Furthermore, each row will need to have an additional column added that will be a checkbox to select which objects in the bindinglist we want to work with.

I thought of possibly making new objects that only have 3 properties on them and take the original 30-property object as a parameter, but I'm not sure that this would be the best implementation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not set `AutoGenerateColumns = false` and add your three columns explicitly?

Comment: "Hey, do we REALLY need to generate all columns manually?  THAT SUCKS" "Okay, here's an AutoGenerate for ya." "Awesome, but we don't want column X" "Okay, just throw a Browsable attribute on that column" "OMG Y R U SO HARD TO USE"